Django Automatic Field Creation
Is there a way to automatically generate a new field when a model that is foreignkeyed is created
    class Metric(models.Model):
    name = CharField(null = True, blank = True, max_length = 200) 
    abbreviation = CharField(null = True, blank = True, max_length = 10)

    def __str__(self):
        try:
            return self.name
        except Exception as e:
            return str(e)
        
class Test(models.Model):
    name = CharField(null = True, blank = True, max_length = 200)
    metrics = ManyToManyField(Metric, null = True, blank = True)

    def __str__(self):
        try:
            return self.name
        except Exception as e:
            return str(e)
        
class TestVariable(models.Model):
    independent_variable = ForeignKey(Variable, null = True, blank = True,on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name = "independent_variables")
    dependent_variable = ForeignKey(Variable, null = True, blank = True, on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name = "dependent_variables")

    test = ForeignKey(Test, null = True, blank = True, on_delete = models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        try:
            return self.name
        except Exception as e:
            return str(e)
    

So if I created a new Metric, is there a way to automatically add a field to TestVariable
for example, if I created a Metric for standard deviation, it would automatically create a field in TestVariable to take a numerical value of the standard deviation.

I bet there's a way to do it with some reflection and factories, but doing this at runtime means that you'd need to also perform migrations at runtime because each new Metric will change the schema. This usually means that you should redesign your schema so that a new Metric doesn't necessitate a schema change in TestVariable. Reducing transitive dependencies between tables (Models) is one of the goals of normalization. TestVariable schema as a function of Metrics is transitive as a consequence of deletion.

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField

class TestVariable(models.Model):
    independent_variable = models.ForeignKey(Variable, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="independent_variables")
    dependent_variable = models.ForeignKey(Variable, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="dependent_variables")
    test = models.ForeignKey(Test, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    metrics_data = JSONField(default=dict)  # This field can store metrics dynamically

    def __str__(self):
        return self.test.name if self.test.name else 'Unnamed TestVariable'

When you create a new Metric, you can update the metrics_data field of TestVariable
